# Gesture FreeDrag performance

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, xna-4.0

I have a simple question, I'm trying to make an huge game for Windows Phone, but I still have a important bottleneck/issue/bad performance.

I've used the mango profiler, but I have seen no problem, infact it's using only 10% cpu on my phone.

Let me show you the problem.

This is my Update

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
        {
            var gs = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
            switch (gs.GestureType)
            {
                case GestureType.FreeDrag:
                    Position += gs.Delta;
                    break;
            }
        }
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

This is my Draw, where map is a 20x15 Texture2D

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();          
        spriteBatch.Draw(map, Position, null, Color.Red, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 1f);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

The problem is that seems that the DRAW is TOO slow for the UPDATE, or kinda of.

For Example:

1) I drag the screen on the right, very slowly -> the map texture is correctly moving on the right

2) I drag the screen on the right, then on the left, quite fast -> the map texture is correctly moving on the right, but has a little lag when moving on the left, like it's still moving on the right..

3) I drag the screen circularly making a circle in 1 second -> well, the map needs 3 seconds to make a move circularly..

What I'm doing wrong??

Should I show you a youtube video??

Thanks you very much!! 
Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIXED!

this was so stupid..

it may happen that we have multiple touch in the same time before the draw, so we have to put a WHILE instead of IF on

```
if (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
```

then it will be

```
while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
```

now it works like a charm!!!

I hope that this will be helpful for people who may have the same problem